# Python selenium webdriver locate and click links

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have a table column with four links in the same cell:

```
<td>
<a href="", onclick=showPricing('1234567','P', 'xyz123456', )>pdf,</a>
<a href="", onclick=showPricing('1234567','C', 'xyz123456', )>csv,</a>
<a href="", onclick=showPricing('1234567','X', 'xyz123456', )>xls,</a>
<a href="", onclick=showPricing('1234567','XP', 'xyz123456', )>xlsp</a>
</td>
```

I want to click the fourth one link text "xlsp", but not able to.

What I tried:

1) `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@onclick, "xyz123456")]').click()`

this of course clicks the first one: pdf

2) `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@onclick, "xyz123456")][contains(text(), "xlsp")]').click()`

this picks the fourth one, but error out with
"....errorElement  could not be scrolled into view" 
3) `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@onclick, "xyz123456")]')[3].click()`

this returns the same error as 2)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To click the fourth forth link with text as **xlsp** you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td a[onclick*='XP']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick,'XP') and contains(.,'xlsp')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: this is basically same as my #2, it doesn't work. when you click(), it always use the URL what is in the href= attribute, which is empty here.

Comment: @Heinz First of all fundamentally there is a lot of difference between your `//a[contains(@onclick, "xyz123456")][contains(text(), "xlsp")]` and `//a[contains(@onclick,'XP') and contains(.,'xlsp')]` within my answer. Moreover, I am sure you haven't considered the **WebDriverWait** I have induced. Let me know the execution status.

Answer (score 0):

I tested multiple options, including @DebanjanB's suggestion, and think this is the most reliable solution:

```
driver.execute_script(dr.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@onclick, "xyz123456")][contains(@onclick, "XP")]').get_attribute("onclick"))
```